How will acetic acid behave in specific solution?
For my experiment I have a 1:1 solution of 1.5 (w/v) chitosan and sodium-alginate (SA) in deionized water separately. Beforehand, I had to dissolve the chitosan-powder in 1% acetic acid solution.
I planned on adding 2 (v/v) glycerol and 0.3 (w/v) Na5P3O10 (Pentasodium-Tripolyphosphate) to form a film through solution casting (picture shows intended experimental outcome).
Unfortunately, the chitosan and SA were not miscible (formation of coacervates). Now, I read that acid environment helps. Thus, I added so much acetic acid until pH of 4 was reached. After that I need to raise the pH to 7 again using NaOH.
Now there must be a lot of acetic acid molecules swimming around. What will they do after I add the Na5P3O10 (and the glycerol + NaOH) to the solution?

Chitosan is the molecule with the NH3+ group.
Source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0141813024012662
I think the acetic acid could interfere with the Na5P3O10 and instead of it occupy the positive charges of the chitosan.
