Why does the NH3+ bond with the terminal oxygen and not another negative group?
I this picture you can see one polysaccharide, containing NH3+ - functional groups, triphosphate, and at the bottom right you have another polysaccharide. My question is:
Why did the terminal oxygen of the triphosphate-molecule bond with NH3+ and not with another negative group (e.g.COO-)?
If this cannot be answered from the picture alone, then please tell me a source about what to look for to predict an outcome of any molecule combination in any environment.


Doesn't look much different from https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/184213/how-will-acetic-acid-behave-in-specific-solution and is much less clear.

This interaction is a hydrogen bond. Like other hydrogen bonds, it requires atoms to be in the right distancevand direction from each other for the bonding overlap to occur. Here the whole molecule is so structured that the hydrogen bond fits as shown; the other phosphate oxygens are not in an optimal position.
